# Creating a self-contained Julia+Jupyter installation

Tags: installation, julia

At my school, there are numerous (Windows) terminal machines I can use. When I log in with my school credentials, I get access to my cloud drive and also some software that comes pre-installed. Julia is not pre-installed on these terminal machines, so I would like to install it on my cloud drive so that I can access it when I log in to a terminal.

This works: I can log in to a terminal, download Julia, install it (I specify the location as my cloud drive), and then install whatever packages I want, and even run JupyterLab installed via conda. Everything works.

Unfortunately, when I log out of the terminal, everything outside my cloud drive is wiped (including any settings like locally set environment variables). Even though the Julia files I downloaded and installed are still there, the installation is completely broken because Julia spread itself to all parts of the computer when I installed it and all those links were severed when I logged out.

My thought was to use environment variables to redirect the locations of various configuration files to my cloud drive so that Julia would know where to look, and then run a batch file upon login to reset those environment variables every time I logged in. Alas, I must have missed some because Julia still doesn't run properly upon re-login. Packages are broken and fail to pre-compile, etc.

Ultimately the only reliable solution I found was to reinstall Julia every time. This is hugely time consuming because of all the packages. Is there some way to create a self-contained installation that is guaranteed to stay inside one directory?

Comment: This is difficult to answer, as it is really conditional to the specific setting in your school. You could get an independent cheap VP and install everything there.. this is what I eneded up doing in my case (I managed to get VSCode online with the Julia extension using JupiterHub, so the students just need a browser)

Comment: Downloading Julia portable version + setting JULIA_DEPOT_PATH to a directory on your network drive should do the job provided that all computers have the same hardware

Comment: @Antonello -- what is a VP?

Comment: @PrzemyslawSzufel -- I downloaded the portable version, set the JULIA_DEPOT_PATH to my network drive, and then tried to install packages. It created .julia in the right place, but the /bin directory it created inside .julia is giving an access denied error. Somehow the way the admins set this up, I found a way to create files on my home directory that I can't delete! Works fine if I don't set JULIA_DEPOT_PATH, but then .julia is put on the local drive and this gets deleted the moment I log out :-(  super frustrating... seems like maybe there is no solution.

Comment: I missed an S.. Virtual Private Server..

Comment: Sometimes on rare occasions some Julia packages on Windows would have wrong access rights when installed. I believe this was patched. If this is your case and it still does not work with Julia 1.10 than it will be hard to figure out unfortunately.